# Как скачать файл с удаленного сервера?

Tags: curl, php

Нужно скачать файлы с удаленного сервера на мой, но у моего хостера ограничение по времени работы скрипта (300 с) и скорость около 100-200 кБ/с. Максимум успевает скачать 15-25 МБ. Нужно хотябы 60. Так что нужно как-то докачать его. 
Сейчас я это сделал так, но файл приходит поврежденный. Что я делаю не так?

```
$url  = 'site.ru/file.mp4';

$size2=getRemoteFileSize($url);// определяем размер файла, работает нормально.

echo $url;
    $path = 'video.mp4';
  $size1=filesize($path)-1;
  $size=$size1.'-'.$size2;
    $fp = fopen($path, 'a');

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, $size); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, надо использовать режим 'ab' (Append/Binary):

    $fp = fopen($path, 'ab');

Comment: А что делает "b"? Гугл не дал внятных ответов) Позволяет записывать побайтно?..